# Unable to read file Matlab Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu

I'm using fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, with Matlab 2015a. 
I have problem with loading .dat file to Matlab. I use same script in my Windows PC, and it works perfectly.

```
dane = load('UW56.dat');
t = dane(:,1);
U_w  = dane(:,2);
I_w  = -dane(:,3);
dt = t(2)-t(1);
```

Here's screenshot of Matlab, you can see I have .dat files in same folder as rest of my files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
load ('UW56.DAT');
```

the name in your files directory is with upper case

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! 
It works now flawlessly. Also if I change .DAT to .dat in file's name it work even better, because I don't have to change anything in others scripts .